# On which site from (Stack Exchange) should someone raise a question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, site-recommendation

Let me first describe my experience before raising this question.

On a couple of occasions a question I've raised, or I engaged through a comment or answer on Stack Overflow was suggested to move to another site of Stack Exchange or was actually moved. In one case it was even downvoted for not being on the correct site.

I've tried to find the possible sites of Stack Exchange, and it's not easy. Usually you have to know about, click there and then after the sign in you can see it on the drop menu on top left bar. Notice, that this bar/menu is not available to all sites.

I've also tried to find a topic/thread/page that provides a list, but most importantly describes what is the purpose of each. The best I could come up with, and that was by accident, was the tag [site-recommendation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) where people ask specifically for the question they have in mind. But they shouldn't in my opinion.

Imagine I want to raise a question, it's my first time to Stack Overflow ecosystem and with Stack Overflow's bulkiness I assume this is the correct space. Yes, there is advice on how to write my question, but there isn't anything about the where should the question be raised. With the voting sometimes providing a feeling of unfair punishment for an easy mistake, the experience of this new user is kind of a bitter one.

Arguably, different sites then it is the problem of the user. But it becomes obvious that it is the same ecosystem. If when creating the account on Stack Overflow, you create it on Stack Exchange as federated authentication. Then, when a moderator can actually move a question from one site to another one, it's even more obvious that it's the same engine powering the each question/comments/answer page.

If I have missed this page then, shouldn't its content be more clear on the "how to ask a question" page? It could be a quick mention that different sites exist with a link to the page that provides the full explanation. For example

> If you question is about server automation then use Server Fault

If there isn't a page, then should one be created and made available at key entry points?

**Clarification Provided after discussion in comments**

It seems that each site has a help center that you find by clicking on the `?` icon on the top bar and then select from the drop down menu. There there is a link with title **What topics can I ask about here?**

For a summary of what each site is intended for, there is an answer on the duplicate question [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) which provides the information I was looking for.

Thanks for @shadow-wizard and @rene for their contribution to produce this clarification.

Comment: We can't possible do that for all the topics that exist. You should be able with the [tour] and [what is on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and the site meta to figure where a question could fit. Then an inspection of the tags and their wiki's you can further limit your options. When still unsure you can always ask on a site Meta.

Comment: But when I read the answers to the questions, there is a sort of understanding. Also, when the different sites were created, I'm sure each had a purpose. What is for example the difference between stackoverflow and stackexchange. This type of information should be summarized somewhere and be sure that it get's the attention of the user quickly. In the same way, you can't miss the how to write the questions guidelines.

Comment: No, we expect users to be able to do some research and find [their answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate link. It wasn't the easiest to find. As a small remark, in the comment of the answer people are suggesting the same thing. I don't understand why @rene dismisses the suggestion that quickly. I'll continue on that link. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you liked the duplicate, that is basically a copy of and link collection to the each sites help center. It still doesn't answer if questions about server automation should be asked on server fault which is what I reacted on. Anyway, problem solved.

Comment: Omg, I had never noticed this type of link https://stackoverflow.com/help. If you had never mentioned help center I would have never seen this.

Comment: We could blame it on the new top bar where the icon in the top right corner with the question mark doesn't get recognized as a link that might reveal help information....  ;)

Comment: I'll update my question with the answer. Thanks @rene

Comment: @AlexSarafian: Usually, answers should go into the answers section and not be edited into the question.

Comment: Ive noticed that if the answer or clarification comes from the same person, then often it's part of the question. I can move it to answer.